# Why are symlinks created when unzipping?

Tags: macos, terminal, symlink

I have a repository where I store all my dotfiles so it's easier to setup a new computer. The repository also contains scripts that install apps, modify my dock, set preferences, update SSH keys, etc. Since the repository updates my SSH keys and modifies my git config, I've found it easier to just download the repository as a ZIP file and then run the starting script (vs. setting up Git manually and then cloning the repository).

However, I just did this to setup a new computer and used `unzip dotfiles.zip` to unzip the repository and it looked like some of my setup actually ran (setting up sym-links).

```
ewiener@laptop repositories % unzip dotfiles.zip 
Archive:  dotfiles.zip
a58722380d39f1f13a3b9ab3238be6abd9c3b5a3
   creating: dotfiles-master/
  inflating: dotfiles-master/.gitconfig  
 extracting: dotfiles-master/.gitignore  
   creating: dotfiles-master/.ssh/
    linking: dotfiles-master/.ssh/.ssh  -> /home/eric/repositories/dotfiles/.ssh 
  inflating: dotfiles-master/.ssh/config  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/.ssh/id_rsa  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/.ssh/known_hosts  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/.ssh/known_hosts.old  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/.vimrc  
   creating: dotfiles-master/OSX/
 extracting: dotfiles-master/OSX/.gitignore_global  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/OSX/.p10k.zsh  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/OSX/.zshrc  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/OSX/Chester.itermcolors  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/OSX/OSX Setup.md  
   creating: dotfiles-master/OSX/OSX Setup/
  inflating: dotfiles-master/OSX/OSX Setup/Screen_Shot_2020-03-24_at_12.29.35_PM.png  
   creating: dotfiles-master/OSX/iterm2_preferences/
  inflating: dotfiles-master/OSX/iterm2_preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/OSX/link_files.sh  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/OSX/setup.sh  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/OSX/setup_dock.sh  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/aliases.zsh  
   creating: dotfiles-master/ubuntu/
 extracting: dotfiles-master/ubuntu/.gitignore_global  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/ubuntu/.p10k.zsh  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/ubuntu/.zshrc  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/ubuntu/computer-setup-ubuntu.md  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/ubuntu/link_files.sh  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/ubuntu/setup.sh  
  inflating: dotfiles-master/ubuntu/use_robot.sh  
finishing deferred symbolic links:
  dotfiles-master/.ssh/.ssh -> /home/eric/repositories/dotfiles/.ssh
```

Why were symlinks created while unzipping the repository?

Comment: Looks like the zip was created with symlinks, see https://serverfault.com/questions/265675/how-can-i-zip-compress-a-symlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because the zip file was created with symlinks.

From the [zip man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip):

> -y |
> --symlinks
>
> For UNIX and VMS (V8.3 and later), store symbolic links as such in the zip archive, instead of compressing and storing the file
> referred to by the link. This can avoid multiple copies of files being
> included in the archive as zip recurses the directory trees and
> accesses files directly and by links.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much! Probably means I had some unexpected symlinks.